# Slim framework JWT middleware Issue

Tags: php, firebase-authentication, slim, middleware, json-web-token

I'm having a problem with my slim app, I'm trying to use JsonWebToken for authentication but I don't know how to do it the right way.

My middleware is blocking all the requests that dont include a valid token, but what about the first authentication post request that obviously don't include a valid token.
Here's my code if it helps (in middleware file):

```
$app->add(function (Request $request,Response $response, $next) use ($app){
    $stringToken = $request->getHeader("Authorization")[0];
    if($stringToken == NULL) {
        return $response->withJson(array("Connection"=>"Fail On Token", "Error"=>"No token Provided."));
    } else {
        $jsonObjectToken = json_decode($stringToken);
        try{
            JWT::decode($jsonObjectToken->jwt, JWTController::$secretKey, array('HS512'));
        }catch (Exception $e){
            return $response->withJson(array("Connection"=>"Fail On Token", "Error"=>$e->getMessage()));
        }
        $response = $next($request, $response);

        return $response;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check which route is called inside the middleware and then do not check the token of the current route is the actual login route.

For getting the route inside the middleware you need first to configure slim to determinate the route before the middleware gets executed:

```
use Slim\App;

$app = new App([
    'settings' => [
        'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true
    ]
])
```

Then you can access the current route with `$route = $request->getAttribute('route');` inside the middleware:

You now can check if the current route is the login route

```
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $route = $request->getAttribute('route');
    $name = $route->getName();

    if($name !== 'login') {
        // do authentication
    } 

    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Note: You need to set the name of the Route with `->setName($name)` on the route like so:

```
$app->get('/login', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // do something
})->setName('login');
```

Comment: I think this tightly couples middleware and routes. If the routes change for any reason, the middleware should change as well. The middleware gets invoked anyway and technically it is not removed from the route but its logic is changed to _do nothing_ for a specific route. Also, this approach seems hard to adopt for already written middlewares. Seems it's not possible to easily remove a middleware from a route once it's been added. Another approach is to write some logic to control which middleware is added to which route.